# Find the prefix which is also a suffix

Tags: string, algorithm, substring

I'm looking for an optimal solution for this problem.

Given a `string s of length n`, find a prefix left-to-right equivalent to a suffix right-to-left.

The prefix and suffix can overlap.

Example: given `abababa`, prefix is `[ababa]ba`, suffix is `ab[ababa]`.

I am able to go till this

1. for each `i = 0 to n-1`, take the prefix ending at i and find if we have an appropriate suffix. It's time is `O(n^2)` time and `O(1)` space.
2. I came up with an optimization where we index the positions of all the characters. This way, we can eliminate set of sample spaces from 1/. Again, the worst case complexity is `O(n^2)` with `O(n)` additional space.

Are there any better algorithm for this ?

Comment: Look at the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm. As part of that algorithm, you find the longest border with this property in time O(n) using space O(n).

Comment: The trivial solution would be to return the whole string :-). Ex. `([abababa)]`. I'm guessing you want the largest possible value other than the aforementioned one?

Comment: Can you show an example where the prefix isn't the same as its reverse? - It isn't clear whether the prefix and suffix both start from the outside (`aab` in `aabxnbaa`), or whether they both start from the left (`aab` in `aabxnaab`, or the entire string, as Kevin mentioned).

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code, take a look.

Comment: Thanks @Danstahr I will take a look. If possible, can you include a brief description abt KMP needle haystack ?

Comment: @MohanKumar: Just take a look at the original paper : http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~shzhang/Combio09/kmp.pdf‎
 or at Wiki : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Answer (score 3):

Make use of the KMP algorithm. The state of the algorithm determines "the longest suffix of the haystack that's still a prefix of the needle". So just take your string as needle and the string without the first character as haystack. Runs in `O(N)` time and `O(N)` space.

An implementation with some examples :

```
public static int[] create(String needle) {
    int[] backFunc = new int[needle.length() + 1];
    backFunc[0] = backFunc[1] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < needle.length(); ++i) {
        int testing = i - 1;
        while (backFunc[testing] != testing) {
            if (needle.charAt(backFunc[testing]) == needle.charAt(i-1)) {
                backFunc[i] = backFunc[testing] + 1;
                break;
            } else {
                testing = backFunc[testing];
            }
        }
    }
    return backFunc;
}

public static int find(String needle, String haystack) {
    // some unused character to ensure that we always return back and never reach the end of the
    // needle
    needle = needle + "$";
    int[] backFunc = create(needle);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(backFunc));
    int curpos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < haystack.length(); ++i) {
        while (curpos != backFunc[curpos]) {
            if (haystack.charAt(i) == needle.charAt(curpos)) {
                ++curpos;
                break;
            } else {
                curpos = backFunc[curpos];
            }
        }
        if (curpos == 0 && needle.charAt(0) == haystack.charAt(i)) {
            ++curpos;
        }
        System.out.println(curpos);
    }
    return curpos;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] tests = {"abababa", "tsttst", "acblahac", "aaaaa"};
    for (String test : tests) {
        System.out.println("Length is : " + find(test, test.substring(1)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple implementation in C#:

```
        string S = "azffffaz";

        char[] characters = S.ToCharArray();
        int[] cumulativeCharMatches = new int[characters.Length];
        cumulativeCharMatches[0] = 0;

        int prefixIndex = 0;
        int matchCount = 0;

        // Use KMP type algorithm to determine matches.

        // Search for the 1st character of the prefix occurring in a suffix.
        // If found, assign count of '1' to the equivalent index in a 2nd array.
        // Then, search for the 2nd prefix character.
        // If found, assign a count of '2' to the next index in the 2nd array, and so on.
        // The highest value in the 2nd array is the length of the largest suffix that's also a prefix.
        for (int i = 1; i < characters.Length; i++)
        {
            if (characters[i] == characters[prefixIndex])
            {
                matchCount += 1;
                prefixIndex += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                matchCount = 0;
                prefixIndex = 0;
            }

            cumulativeCharMatches[i] = matchCount;
        }

        return cumulativeCharMatches.Max();
```

Comment: Nice solution, but answer would have been much better if you had explained it better and also in the answer section instead of just putting in comments.

Answer (score 0):

See:

http://algorithmsforcontests.blogspot.com/2012/08/borders-of-string.html

for an O(n) solution

The code actually calculates the index of the last character in the prefix. For the actual prefix/suffix, you will need to extract the substring from 0 to j (both included, length is j+1)